# How Can I Avoid Bad, Ugly Coding Habits When Mixing CakePHP, jQuery And Qtip2 In A PHP Page?

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0, qtip2

I'm building what will be a very information-heavy game screen, and, with even just the first bit of code, which displays a number of planets on the screen, my code is starting to look a bit messy/complicated.

I'd also like to hide some of it from the uses looking at "view source", if posible, but that's a secondary concern.

Basically, the code below draws X planets at various Absolute positions on the screen, and provides a mouseover tooltip for each planet.

There simply must be a "nicer" and/or more efficient way to do this? I'd appreciate any tips, basically.

My main reason for being concerned is that the Qtip2 tooltips are going to become a lot more complex, and there'll be all sorts of player info added to the page, and a couple of chat/news/info boxes. I don't want to *start* with spaghetti code, when I've still got the main course to deliver to the page!

I think my main concern is the masses of script tags I'll be generating. At the rate of one per tooltip that I add to the page. The "echo"s for the planet images (and their labels) are surely unavoidable....I don't really know, I';m a bit new to this.

```
<!-- File: /app/View/Games/main.ctp -->
<?php

    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.8.2.min');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery.qtip');

    $game = $this->Session->read('Game');
?>
<?php
    foreach ($game['Planet'] as $planet) {
        echo $this->Html->image('../img/planet/' . $planet['planet_image_file'] .'.png', array('class' => 'planet_img planet_' . $planet['id'], 'id' => 'planet_' . $planet['id'], 'alt' => $planet['planet_name'], 'style' => 'position:absolute;top:' . $planet['y_position'] . 'px;left:' . $planet['x_position'] . 'px;'));
        echo '<script>$(\'.planet_' . $planet['id'] . '\').qtip({content: \'' . $planet['planet_name'] . '\'});</script>';
        echo '<label for="' . $planet['planet_name'] . $planet['id'] . '" style="position:absolute;top:' . ($planet['y_position'] - 20) . 'px;left:' . $planet['x_position'] . 'px;">' . $planet['planet_name'] . '</label>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use stylesheets instead of all those inline styles. If you add styles dynamically, you could always have a `<style>` element in the header, to which you dynamically append css definitions as needed.
2. Use image sprites to help with optimisation. This is more appropriate for manipulating background images, rather than inline images, but for the performance gains it offers, it may be worth it.

   You would need elements using css image backgrounds, not inline images, but the DOM can be just as simple.
3. Instead of calling a bunch of scripts to add the qtip thingy, have the information qtip needs as a data attribute for each of these elements, and have one function, in  an external js file, which loops through the elements and does the qtip stuff based on the data attribute.

   foreach ($game['Planet'] as $planet) {
           echo $this->Html->image('../img/planet/' . $planet['planet_image_file'] .'.png', array('class' => 'planet_img planet_' . $planet['id'], 'id' => 'planet_' . $planet['id'], 'alt' => $planet['planet_name'], 'data-planet-name' => $planet['planet_name']));
           echo '' . $planet['planet_name'] . '';
       }

jQuery

```
$('.planet_img').each(function(){
  $(this).qtip({content: $(this).data('planet-name')});
})
```

Comment: Number 3's a great idea, and I'll definitely act on that. The problem with number 1 is that I could be drawing any number of planets to the screen. But, your point 3 could serve just as well for point 1.

Could you explain point 2, further, please? Image sprites? How do sprites relate to HTML image tags?

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Well, to really avail of css image sprites, the image needs to be a css background image, not inline. But you can do it with just as few elements ( divs instead of imgs, for example ) and it will make things load quicker.

Comment: I see (well, I don't, really, but I'll Google what you're talking about). I'll try out what you've suggested so far and come back to accept the answer later if I can get it working.

Comment: Would you mind expanding upon point 3, please?

I removed my inline qtip scripts and instead included a link to an external javascript file, which currently contains a cut 'n paste of your jQuery snippet above. But, nothing happens when I mouseover a planet image...Should that jQuery snippet be inside this: $(document).ready(function(){?

Comment: Also, when the qtips were appearing, they were just appearing on the far left of my screen, as though I was just adding paragraph elements, and not vanishing upon mouseout...but I fear that may have to be another question! :)

Comment: Yes, it would need to be applied at the right time, so `$(document).ready()` or any other time you load elements you want qtip to be applied to.

Are you using the qtip stylesheets in your page?

Comment: Okay, facepalm about the CSS. Thanks. That works nicely. Answer accepted, and I'll look into the image stuff you mentioned. Appreciated.

Comment: Actually, can I put my entire $planet object in the custom parameter, and access it in the jQuery? If so, how? I've got more than just the planet name that will need to go in the tooltip, you see. Since I don't want all the data for all the planets to just be lying around in the source view, should I perhaps look into using Ajax tooltips in Qtip2?

Comment: Ah-ha, I've done it, thanks. I managed to figure out how to encode my planet data as a JSON array, and get the jQuery, erm, thingy, to read it. I'm just off to post a follow-on question....